# weblogic setup Issue: Server start leads to "Server subsystem failed" Error

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic, installation

// This the server log for the error

```
<May 2, 2014 3:30:52 PM IST> <Critical> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000386> <Server subsystem failed. Reason: java.lang.Assert
ionError: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at weblogic.descriptor.DescriptorManager$SecurityServiceImpl$SecurityProxy._invokeServiceMethod(DescriptorManager.java:175)
        at weblogic.descriptor.DescriptorManager$SecurityServiceImpl$SecurityProxy.decrypt(DescriptorManager.java:192)
        at weblogic.descriptor.DescriptorManager$SecurityServiceImpl.decrypt(DescriptorManager.java:114)
        at weblogic.descriptor.internal.AbstractDescriptorBean._decrypt(AbstractDescriptorBean.java:1191)
        at weblogic.management.configuration.SecurityConfigurationMBeanImpl.getCredential(SecurityConfigurationMBeanImpl
.java:781)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at weblogic.descriptor.DescriptorManager$SecurityServiceImpl$SecurityProxy._invokeServiceMethod(DescriptorManage
r.java:173)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: weblogic.security.internal.encryption.EncryptionServiceException
        at weblogic.security.internal.encryption.JSafeEncryptionServiceImpl.decryptBytes(JSafeEncryptionServiceImpl.java
:139)
        at weblogic.security.internal.encryption.JSafeEncryptionServiceImpl.decryptString(JSafeEncryptionServiceImpl.jav
a:187)
        at weblogic.security.internal.encryption.ClearOrEncryptedService.decrypt(ClearOrEncryptedService.java:96)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<May 2, 2014 3:30:52 PM IST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to FAILED.>
<May 2, 2014 3:30:52 PM IST> <Error> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000383> <A critical service failed. The server will shut itse
lf down.>
<May 2, 2014 3:30:52 PM IST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to FORCE_SHUTTING_DOWN.>
```

I've just setup the weblogic domain and updated JDBC pool and deployment detailas in the xml files itself.
Now, when trying to start the server, It's throwing the above error.

Comment: It's failing on a `decrypt`. Did you type passwords into the files you edited?

Answer (score 3):

The file **SerializedSystemIni.dat** may have become corrupted. The Admin Server fails to start because it is no longer able to decrypt the credentials that are stored in the config.xml file in your $DOMAIN_HOME/config directory.

If you replace the encrypted credentials that are stored in this file with plain text valuies, you should be able to start your Admin Server again.

Source:
http://weblogicscripting.blogspot.nl/2014/04/unable-to-start-admin-server-bea-000386.html

Also see the following Oracle Support note:
**How to Recover SerializedSystemIni.dat File? (Doc ID 1602857.1)**

After successfully starting the Admin Server, the values will be re-encrypted again.
I just experienced the same issue and managed to start my server, but be aware that other stored password may have become unreadable as well - check for any errors in the log file, such as for example the credentials for a data source.

Answer (score 1):

In your domains/config, change config.xml properties from encrypted to Simple Text.
Properties to be changed:

```
 <embedded-ldap>
<credential-encrypted>Simple Text</credential-encrypted>
  </embedded-ldap>
```

and

```
 <security-configuration>
<credential-encrypted>Simple Text</credential-encrypted>
 <node-manager-username>WEBLOGICUSERNAME</node-manager-username>
<node-manager-password-encrypted>WEBLOGICPASSWORD</node-manager-password-encrypted>
 </security-configuration>
```